# Ориентированный граф с расстояниями

Tags: c#, графы, c, c++

Привет всем)
Как можно реализовать граф ориентированный с расстояниями вершин.
Т.е. 
На входе вершина A, вершина B, и расстояние между ними 6. 
И B C расстояние между ними 3.
И A C расстояние между ними 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уточните, что значит реализовать? Представить в памяти? Тогда в простейшем случае (если не очень большой граф - а скорее всего в учебном задании так), достаточно матрицы смежности с весами, в которой на пересечении строки I и столбца J будет располагаться вес - стоимость перехода из I в J. Под весом может пониматься всё, что угодно, в том числе расстояние (семантика определяется задачей).

Матрица для вашего примера может выглядеть так, если, как вы написали, граф ориентированный, т.е. раз явно не написано, что из B можно попасть в A, считаем, что нельзя:

```
0 6 1
0 0 3
0 0 0
```

Или так, если вы все-таки предполагаете существование и обратных дуг графа:

```
0 6 1
6 0 3
3 1 0
```

В данном случае нуль обозначает отсутствие дуги. Если задача подразумевает возможность "мгновенного перехода" или наличие пути нулевой стоимости, то отсутствие следует обозначать по-другому, чтобы избежать коллизий. Например, если по смыслу задачи невозможны дуги отрицательного веса (когда вам платят за проезд по данной дуге), можно взять -1. Короче, всё очень сильно зависит от специфики задачи.

Для более крупных графов, обладающих специальной структурой, могут потребоваться более интересные структуры данных. Тут остается посоветовать вооружиться хорошей книгой по алгоритмам - Седжвик, Кормен и т.д.

Comment: Вот через матрицу сойдет, а как это все реализовать?
Как с ними обращаться?

Comment: Т.е. без визуализации)))

Answer (score 1):

Списком смежности

то есть например у вас 3 вершины A,B,C

и на каждую вершину вешается список смежных вершин c весом ребра

для вершины A: (B,6), (C,1)

для вершины B: (C,3)

для вершины C: -

Сами вершины также можно преставить списком (то есть получится список списков)

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя никак,так как 3+1<6. Такой треугольник невозможен на плоскости.

Comment: там ведь не сказано, что граф долюен быть цикличным

Comment: в условии не сказано, во-первых, что речь вообще идет о визуальном представлении на плоскости (отрисовке), во-вторых, что дуга должна строго изображаться отрезком прямой, в-третьих, что расстояние понимается в евклидовом смысле.

Answer (score 0):

я бы реализовал так:

есть класс Vertex, содержит название, и айдишник; есть класс Edge - содержит 2 айдишника вершин, старта и конца, это важно, т.к. граф должен быть ореинтированным, и длину между ними.

и есть класс Graph, который содержит 2 списка:

- список вершин
- список рёбер

отрисовывать следующим образом: идём по списку рёбер и рисуем их, рисуя соответственные вершины по айдишникам старта и конца.

Comment: есть минусы (поиск смежных вершин, поиск ребра)
из плюсов только память (но в списке смежности она такая же)

Comment: и что ж сложного в поиске смежных вершин? выбираем из списка рёбер те, в которых присутсвует искомая вершина, а потом выбираем из этих рёбер вторую вершину(начальную и/или конечную в зависимости от надобности), не более чем O(n). В поиске ребра тоже всё уложится в O(n)

Comment: Не забывайте ребер может быть |V|^2 примерно (где |V| - количество вершин)

Comment: я бы эту величину умножил ещё на два, т.к. рёбра могут быть и обратные, хотя я не думаю, что в такой тривиальной задаче кол-во вершин будет уж таким колоссальным.

Comment: Умножать не надо, т.к. как раз если граф направленный, то максимальное количество ребер (|V|^2-|V|), видно как раз на матрице смежности (по главной диагонали нет ребер)
Это все при условии что между 2мя вершинами в одном направлении может быть одно ребро и нет петель

Comment: да, вы правы, запямятовал формулу - n(n-1) - всё верно. А регулировать кол-во рёбер в одном направление и отсутствие петель тоже не сложно

Comment: Ну регулировать их можно, если задача не на поток) Хотя и в таком случае тоже не сложно